# How do I edit page title/path (?) display in React?

Tags: reactjs, page-title

Is there a name that React apps use to refer to this section of the page which describes where the user is within the website? I cannot seem to find it in the code base.

I am referring to the section that says "Clinics / AT Clinic" in this image:
[image: I am refering to the section that says "Clinics / AT Clinic" in this image]

Comment: Your question is not clear... You're talking about that breadcrumb?

Comment: @dududornelees is correct. That component is typically called a "breadcrumb" and if you'd like help editing it, you'll need to provide your code.

Comment: We won't give you the code to do that. If you want this, you're in the incorrect place. We should just give you the "path" to find what you want. So, I won't provide a code for you.

Comment: I don't want the code, 'breadcrumb' is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this is being rendered dynamically, and you can get the current path of the window with `window.location.pathname`

You can try global searching `window.location.pathname`